# How to optimize the event polling thread on a single-core machine having <500 MHz clock, <256 MiB RAM and using Customize Linux based on Yocto minimal

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

Currently, I have made an embedded GUI application for one of my embedded boards (Galileo Gen 2). The application can perform testing activity for I²C, SPI, GPIO, ADC, UART, and PWM, including their PinMuxing.

For GPIO I have used the sysfs-based rising/falling edge interrupt detection technique. For that inside the low-level code I have invoked the GPIO PIN monitor thread which has a poll() system call based logic (fd state monitor). So basically if any interrupt occurs on a GPIO PIN then I have filled a buffer with event information, like RTC stamp, PIN value, etc.

Now in the another thread, it will read that buffer for logging.

Both threads are synchronized using a conditional variable.

After implementing the above logic my application becomes slower as compared to the previous one. I think due to my low hardware configuration based platform, the GUI rendering is slow because the above two threads are in a `while` loop. The `top` utility gives me the 100% CPU utilization while testing the above scenario.

Or is there another thread optimization technique required?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. You have one thread calling `poll` waiting for a hardware event, which fills a buffer, and a second thread reading this buffer? How is the second thread notified? Which thread runs with 100% CPU?

Comment: If buffer is filled with event info then and only the    Poll thread will notify  to consumer/reader thread. Otherwise consumer thread will wait with specified timeout. How to profile multithreaded program...I really dont know so i cant tell you which thread using 100% CPU. But you know what both threads are in while(true) loop to perform production and consumption activity continuously

Comment: On a single core machine (I've coded on several), the design imperative becomes: every thread must be a "good neighbor".  In practice, this means that every thread must 'wait-on-something' (message input? brief pause? semaphore signal?), before proceeding with its activity, and then with the urgent goal of getting back to the waiting as soon as possible.  Polling, this is not.  Also remember that a thread context switch is 1000 times slower than a method invocation.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN thanks. My poll() thread and reader thread are 'wait-on-something' based on event buffer fill or not and using conditional variable(Semaphore alternative IPC). so 'polling' terms in my case is different  as you specified "Polling, this is not".

Comment: If the threads are looping with no sleep time, it is normal you'd have a 100%CPU usage IMHO.

Comment: Is there any other technique to protect this ? Other then sleep?

Comment: @Gar ... Is there any thread optimisation standard for embedded platforms? Right now I am using c++11 standard with thread class to perform all above my activities

Comment: Sleep is already a good option, your problem as i understand is not really "thread" related, you have some code scanning all the time some inputs, this code must give some cpu time to other processes (sleep does that).

Comment: You have a bug. The threads should already be waiting (either in `poll` or on the condition variable) and should not be burning the CPU. You really want to find and fix this bug, not hide it with a sleep.

Answer (score -1):

> is there another thread optimization technique required?

Without looking at your code, I probably can't recommend much.

The comment about GUI rendering catches my eye. Console graphic I/O can be surprisingly expensive (which I'm sure is why all on-line adverts are filled with pictures and graphics, and minimal text).

I'm not sure, however, if text I/O would be any better than graphics / pictures. More to learn.

---

This is polling if 'checking the flag' does not block:

```
while (1)
   if(flag)   // Non-blocking
      do_something();
```

This snippet is polling the flag that presumably something else will set (if it ever gets CPU cycles to do so.)

When "if(flag)" blocks the thread, you probably can't do much better.

---

Polling, this is not:

```
while (1)
   if(flag)   // Non-blocking
      do_something();
   else
      usleep(minValue); // When included, it can be remarkably effective
```

I'm not sure if this works on any form of Linux, and I don't know what the minValue idea is for Linux. See next.

---

Polling, this is not (part 2): At least one reason why embedded system support is special:

VxWorks provides `delay()`:

```
while (1)
   if(flag)  // Non-blocking
      do something();
   else
      delay(0);
```

Typically, delay(10) surrenders the processor (as a good neighbor would) and requests to be restored to the back of the appropriate priority thread queue after 10 milliseconds.

In this I'm-not-polling loop, "delay(0)" forces the scheduler to 'move' the current thread to the back of the current thread priority queue.

Note that if there is no other thread in the same ready-to-run queue, the thread is instantly at the front again, would simply be resumed, with much less than normal context switch expense.

---

It was awesome how light duty (in CPU cycles) the `while` loop with delay(0) was to that embedded system ... VxWorks has several of these kinds of 'tricks'.

It is remarkable how light duty (in CPU cycles) the while loop is with `usleep(minValue)` on my Linux. Even though the context switch is relatively expensive, it is still grease to the bearings.

It is almost environmentally criminal (in terms of heat generated) how heavy the poll loop is, in any context.

Comment: So you mean, should I use sleep syscall to optimize the overall application performance?

Comment: @BhoomilChavda -- In most systems, the shortest duration sleep is surprisingly big (possibly 10,000 ns, or 10 ms).  So what I  was thinking is you might try to find out what is the shortest sleep is on your system, and then, if it is not outrageously big (relative to the context switch and other factors) try it ...  see if you gain performance.

Comment: Why are you mention context switch of thread ? Is that really critical one ? OS scheduler will handle it. If im not putting sleep in between then scheduler feel load and that is why i have rendering issue with GUI. After studying all comments n answer i think i need to put sleep over there. You know what i hate sleep because I can not leverage the cpu clock

Comment: Because your post asks "Or is there any other thread optimization technique required?" and seems to me, in general, inquiring about threads.  On a single core machine, all the threads must 'take-turns' with the CPU.  The OS will provide some scheduling support, and there is more than one scheduler available to try. (I think 1 at a time)

Comment: By putting 1msec sleep it gives me overall good performance as compared to without sleep

Comment: Congrats. Human visible behaviour improvement by reducing cpu stress ... non-linear systems are interesting.

Comment: I might have missed some hint with the 'why are you mention context switch of thread' question.  It is an excellent question ... let me know if you would like me to attempt a summary additional answer to this post ... about Linux, threads vs processes, and maybe some other stuff.  I know nothing about your target hw, except what you have told us (good info)  Yocto I have read about, but never used.  So my additions would be generic.